# how to format sublists in a tabular way automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, nested-lists

I have the following list, which contains sublists

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

My aim is to format them that way

```
  apples    Alice     dogs
 oranges      Bob     cats
cherries    Carol    moose
  banana    David    goose
```

The code below do that

```
In [55]: for nested_list in zip(*tableData):
             print("{:>9} {:>9} {:>9}".format(*nested_list))
```

Yet what bugs me is I need to specify manually the format of each sublist.

I've been trying to find a way to do it automatically with a for loop but I did not find anything relevant on how to do it.

Any tips are more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for line in zip(*tableData):
    for word in line:
        print("{:>9}".format(word), end=' ')
    print()
```

Explanation

---

If the `print()` was absent, all the sublists would be put on a single line like this

```
  apples     Alice      dogs   oranges       Bob      cats  cherries     Carol     moose    banana     David     goose
```

The `print()` allows a newline

Comment: hi @nutmeg64, that's great one. What is the use of `print()` at the end, please?

Comment: Just printing a newline

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use `{:>9}` as the format code with an arbitrary number of columns, try this:

```
fieldFormat = ' '.join(['{:>9}'] * len(tableData))
for nestedList in zip(*tableData):
    print(fieldFormat.format(*nestedList))
```

This just creates a list of `{:>9}` format specifiers, one for each column in tableData, then joins them together with spaces.

If you want to automatically calculate the field widths as well, you can do this:

```
fieldWidths = [max(len(word) for word in col) for col in tableData]
fieldFormat = ' '.join('{{:>{}}}'.format(wid) for wid in fieldWidths)
for nestedList in zip(*tableData):
    print(fieldFormat.format(*nestedList))
```

`fieldWidths` is generated from a list comprehension that calculates the maximum length of each word in each column.  From the inside:

```
(len(word) for word in col)
```

This is a generator that will produce the length of each word in `col`.

```
max(len(word) for word in col)
```

Feeding the generator (or any iterable) into `max` will calculate the maximum value of everything produced by the iterable.

```
[max(len(word) for word in col) for col in tableData]
```

This list comprehension produces the maximum length of all words in each column `col` of data in `tableData`.

`fieldFormat` is then produded by transforming `fieldWidths` into format specifiers.  Again from the inside:

```
'{{:>{}}}'.format(wid)
```

This formats `wid` into the `{:>#}` format.  `{{` is a way to have a format specifier produce a `{`; similarly, `}}` produces `}`.  The `{}` in the middle is what actually gets formatted with `wid`.

```
('{{:>{}}}'.format(wid) for wid in fieldWidths)
```

This is a generator function that does the above formatting for each width listed in fieldWidths.

```
fieldFormat = ' '.join('{{:>{}}}'.format(wid) for wid in fieldWidths)
```

This just joins those formats together with spaces in between to create the `fieldFormat` format specifier.

Comment: hi @j-earls, would you mind putting some explanation for your second part, please. It would definitely help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow @j-earls. That's brilliant. Thank you very much for your kind explanation. I owe you, I mean it. If we meet one day, diner or lunch or breakfast is on me.

Comment: Just corrected the answer (again) - I had swapped the `:` and `>` in the format specifier in the 2nd example.  Should be good now.